# My php mvc application works on windows but not working on linux

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I created a php mvc app it works fine on Windows but on linux it shows 500 error, without any other informations.
the app is divided on two folder app and public
public : index.php and assets ... .htaccess
app : show the bottom of the question
my index.php

```
    <?php
    namespace PHPMVC;
    use PHPMVC\LIB\FrontController;
    
    if (!defined('DS'))
    {
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
    
    require_once '..'.DS.'app'.DS.'config.php';
    require_once '..'.DS.'app'.DS.'models'.DS.'database'.DS.'database.php';
    require_once APP_PATH.''.DS.'lib'.DS.'autoload.php';
    
//if I comment the next two lines it shows a white page
    $frontcontroller = new FrontController();
    $frontcontroller->dispatch();
```

my FrontController.php file

```
    <?php
    
    
    namespace PHPMVC\LIB;
    
    
    class FrontController
    {
        const NOT_FOUND_ACTION = 'notFoundAction' ;
        const NOT_FOUND_CONTROLLER = 'notFoundController' ;
    
    
        private $_controller ='index';
        // private $_controller ='home';
        private $_action = 'view'; // was default
        private $_params = array();
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->_parseUrl();
        }
    
        private function _parseUrl()
        {
              $url  = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) , '/'), 3);
              if(isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != '')
              {
                  $this->_controller = $url[0];
              }
              if(isset($url[1]) && $url[1] != '')
                {
                    $this->_action = $url[1];
                }
              if(isset($url[2]) && $url[2] != '')
                {
                    $this->_params = explode('/', $url[2] );
                }
        }
    
        public function dispatch()
        {

            $controllerClassName = ucfirst($this->_controller) . 'Controller';
            $controllerClassName = 'PHPMVC\CONTROLLERS\\' . $controllerClassName;
    
            $actionName = $this->_action . 'Action';
    
            if(!class_exists($controllerClassName))
            {
                $controllerClassName = 'PHPMVC\CONTROLLERS\\'. self::NOT_FOUND_CONTROLLER;
            }
            $controller = new $controllerClassName();
    
            if(!method_exists($controller, $actionName ))
            {
                $this->_action = $actionName = self::NOT_FOUND_ACTION;
            }
    
    
            $controller->setController($this->_controller);
            $controller->setAction($this->_action);
            $controller->setParams($this->_params);
            $controller->$actionName();
    
        }
    }
```

the app folder

```
.
|-- config.php
|-- controllers
|   |-- AbstractController.php
|   |-- FileController.php
|   |-- HomeController.php
|   |-- IndexController.php
|   |-- LoginController.php
|   |-- MessageController.php
|   |-- NotFoundController.php
|   |-- PortfolioController.php
|   |-- PostController.php
|   |-- PresentationController.php
|   |-- ServiceController.php
|   |-- SocialController.php
|   |-- StaffController.php
|   `-- UserController.php
|-- error_log
|-- lib
|   |-- Autoload.php
|   `-- FrontController.php
|-- models
|   |-- AbstractModel.php
|   |-- LoginModel.php
|   |-- MessageModel.php
|   |-- PortfolioModel.php
|   |-- PostModel.php
|   |-- PresentationModel.php
|   |-- ServiceModel.php
|   |-- SocialModel.php
|   |-- StaffModel.php
|   |-- UserModel.php
|   `-- database
|       `-- Database.php
`-- views
    |-- file
    |   |-- delete.view.php
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- notallowed.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notfoundfile.view.php
    |   |-- notuploaded.view.php
    |   |-- upload.view.php
    |   |-- uploaded.view.php
    |   `-- view.view.php
    |-- home
    |   `-- view.view.php
    |-- index
    |   `-- view.view.php
    |-- login
    |   |-- failed.view.php
    |   |-- logout.view.php
    |   |-- redirect.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- welcome.view.php
    |-- message
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- read.view.php
    |   |-- replay.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- wrong.view.php
    |-- notfound
    |   |-- notfound.view.php
    |   `-- noview.view.php
    |-- portfolio
    |   |-- add.view.php
    |   |-- added.view.php
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- edit.view.php
    |   |-- notadded.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- wrong.view.php
    |-- post
    |   |-- add.view.php
    |   |-- added.view.php
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- edit.view.php
    |   |-- notadded.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- wrong.view.php
    |-- presentation
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   `-- view.view.php
    |-- service
    |   |-- add.view.php
    |   |-- added.view.php
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- edit.view.php
    |   |-- notadded.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- wrong.view.php
    |-- social
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   `-- view.view.php
    |-- staff
    |   |-- add.view.php
    |   |-- added.view.php
    |   |-- deleted.view.php
    |   |-- edit.view.php
    |   |-- notadded.view.php
    |   |-- notdeleted.view.php
    |   |-- notupdated.view.php
    |   |-- updated.view.php
    |   |-- view.view.php
    |   `-- wrong.view.php
    |-- template
    |   |-- footer.inc.php
    |   |-- header.inc.php
    |   `-- sidebar.inc.php
    |-- templatefront
    |   |-- footer.inc.php
    |   |-- header.inc.php
    |   `-- sidebar.inc.php
    `-- user
        |-- add.view.php
        |-- added.view.php
        |-- deleted.view.php
        |-- edit.view.php
        |-- existed.view.php
        |-- notadded.view.php
        |-- notdeleted.view.php
        |-- notupdated.view.php
        |-- othercompte.view.php
        |-- rootuser.view.php
        |-- updated.view.php
        |-- view.view.php
        `-- wrong.view.php

20 directories, 121 files
```

I tried to change the controllers files names to match each controller class name but it didn't work

Comment: Two quick things to check, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see the error. Also, check the case of the filename (eg: maybe your filename is Frontcontroller with a lowercase C.) - some Linux systems are case sensitive on file names.

Comment: thanks, it shows me this error : 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpmvc\lib\FrontController' not found in /home/medstock/public_html/public/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/medstock/public_html/public/index.php on line 21

Comment: Windows system is not case sensitive while Linux is case sensitive. E.g. your directory name is `app` and you use like `App` in you code as a path then it will work on Windows and not in Linux. for linux you must use small case `app`.